# hook_node_insert and FileField Paths

Tags: 7, media

I'm using hook_node_insert to process some data from node.

This code returns image URL, BUT i'm using FileField Paths and i can't manage to get the final image URL. Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
$fid = $node->field_imagen['und'][0]['fid'];
$imgpath = file_load($fid)->uri;
$url = file_create_url($imgpath);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filefield Path uses hook_entity_insert() to operate with file directory. The hook_node_insert is called before hook_entity_insert, so the file isn't processed yet there.
See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7

```
module_invoke_all('node_' . $op, $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_' . $op, $node, 'node');
```

You should use that hook as well. Just make sure, your module have higher weight than ffp. (Check (and increase if necessary) the weight field of your module in the system table.)

Comment: I've been trying to make it work but i can't.
Where should i use module_invoke_all and how do i get the vars from it?
I can only get the final image url from entity_insert, but i can't pass the variable to node_insert...

what about `module_invoke('filefield_paths', 'entity_insert', $node, 'node')`?

Comment: It was just a part of node_save, you never need to use that code. Just do whatever want you do, but not in you module MODULE_node_insert function, do it in MODULE_entity_insert. :)